# DynamoDB architecture for many to many relationships

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to DynamoDB and I'm trying to wrap my head around the best way to structure my data.  I read from their docs that most well architecture dynamo databases typically only need one table.  While i know that's not a rule, I'm keeping it in consideration when I'm designing the schema.

The core components of the app goes as follows:

- Users can register as a coach, athlete or parent
- Coaches can create Teams that athletes and parents can be apart of
- Each team will have multiple events (games, practices, showcases, etc).  Each one of those events, players may or may not attend.
- Each user type (coach, athlete, parent) can the ability to post an status update/photo/video

The relationships between these entities would look like this:

- Users -> Teams = many to many
- Teams -> Users = many to many
- Events -> Users = many to many
- Team -> Events = many to many
- Events -> Team = 1 to many
- Users -> Events = many to many
- User -> Posts = 1 to many

Using these features I need to be able to answer the following questions

- get teams by user ID
- get users by team ID
- get events by user ID
- get events by team ID
- get posts by team ID
- get posts by user ID
- get friends by user ID
- get all teams by sport
- get all players by sport

With these details, can someone tell me if using a single table would be a good choice?  If so, what partition and range keys would I use?  Would I also set up a GSI?

Comment: Why are you using DynamoDB and not Postgres, MySQL or Aurora in RDS, for example? This would be a very simple a straighforward DB schema in a SQL DB. Dynamo is very hard to get architected the right way and, if you don't do it right, it will bite you in the future. See [this](https://syslog.ravelin.com/you-probably-shouldnt-use-dynamodb-89143c1287ca) and [this](https://read.acloud.guru/why-amazon-dynamodb-isnt-for-everyone-and-how-to-decide-when-it-s-for-you-aefc52ea9476).

Comment: This is pretty clearly a relational database workload.  It isn't clear why you would even *consider*  trying to implementing this with DynamoDB, as this seems to be quite a bit outside its intended use cases.  What is your motivation?

Comment: I guess you guys both make great points.  Only chose dynamo because it was real easy to set up w/ appsync and something I wanted to learn and from some videos and articles i read it appeared dynamo could handle many-to-many.  But now that I think about it, just because it can, doesn't mean I should.  Guess I'll take a look at Aurora instead.  Thanks!